# dropdown flexibility?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have this dropdown and currently it's allowing multiple selection. However, I would like to **ONLY** allow one selection at a time. Basically, if I choose person1 (this should be the only one selected), then if I choose person2 (person2 should be the only one selected). Can anyone tell me how to make this happen? Thank you!

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-bhvrkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="people" [showHeader]="false"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: Do you have to use the `p-multiselect` component? You could get what you want with the [p-dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown).

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, but it seems like you shouldn't be using a **multi**Select control if you only want to allow a single selection.

Comment: That control is terrible, has no keyboard accessibility and looks crap. I would avoid using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement. I think you are looking something like below. 
Use (onChange) method in your multiselect.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="people" [showHeader]="false" 
     (onChange)="change($event)">
</p-multiSelect>
```

And in your respective **component.ts** file . Just Use below

```
 change(e:any){
    if(e.value.length > 1) {
      e.value.shift();
    }
  }
```

I hope this will serve your purpose. Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-nb2fwm)

Comment: your solution produces a bug. Let's say I choose person2 and then I want to select another one (Example: person4). I can't do it anymore. Do you know how to allow a user to select an option at least once?

Comment: @progx updated my change function. `e.value.shift();` now I am using shift() function to achieve this. You can select only one user at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Please check [this link](https://primeng-input-multiselect-9t1miq.stackblitz.io) for dropdown option:

html

```
<p-dropdown   [options]="people" ></p-dropdown>
```

module

```
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ..., DropdownModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Edit** OP insists on using multiselect

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="people" [showHeader]="false" selectionLimit="1"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: @Simoare I want to use the checkboxes though. Your solution doesn't use the checkboxes

Comment: @progx Why do you want the checkboxes if only one can be selected?

Comment: @IvanS95 It's a requirement.  Also, I want to be able to clear out the dropdown in case the user doesn't want any option.